# Receiving String saved wrong in the database

Tags: javascript, sql-server, express

I have an API using Express.js that receives data from Sigfox(A service for IoT) and inserts the data into the  SQL Server Express database, this data comes in 4 different URL with this format:
http://servername:port/api/mediciones/sigfox_libelium/aire/2059E7/230934644ae17a8441/1626762070/9

My solution to insert all the data, is to create an array and fill it with the parsed data from the all 4 URL.

```
    [
'2059E7',
 64,
 16.559999465942383,
 98.3505859375,
 100161.21875,
 1.7199997901916504,
 3.1599998474121094,
 16.219999313354492
]
```

When the last request comes and the array is filled, an Insert is made into the database table:

```
 .query("INSERT INTO medicionAire(fecha,id, bateria, temperatura, humedad, presionatmosferica, pm1, pm2, pm10) VALUES(SYSDATETIME()," + dimensiones[0] + ", "+ dimensiones[1] + ", " + dimensiones[2] + ", " + dimensiones[3] + ", " + dimensiones[4] + ", " + dimensiones[5] + ", " + dimensiones[6] + ", " + dimensiones[7] + ");")
```

where Dimensiones[] is the array filled with data.

ID should be "2059E7" like in the URL but when saved looks like this

[image]

EDIT: This is the Design of the table, column id is a Varchar, not a num, but looks like is being treated as a number

[image]

Comment: I *suspect* the problem is you are **injecting** the values, not parametrising. As a result the  value `2059E7` is interpreted as the floating point value `20590000000`, which can also be written as `2.059E+10`. That or your `id` column is a `real`? I ***hope*** not...

Comment: Include the schema of your `medicionAire` table in your question.

Comment: @Stu here is the design of the table.

Comment: @Larnu the id column is a varchar, and yeah im injecting the data... I couldn´t make it work parametrising and decided to go the fast way in order to have results in a short time... so I guess thats the problem.

Comment: That would make sense then, @Luisurrechaga , If you do `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20),2059E7);` you get the same result. Parametrise, with strongly typed data, and you remove the problem.

Comment: What's the typical maximum length of an ID value? If you set the column to something more suitable eg `varchar(6)` you'll encounter the error on insert and be closer to debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

In your database the data type of `id` is a numeric type (float, int, decimal...) and therefore the value `2059E7`, which is a mathematical notation for 2059 multiplied by 10000000 (7 zeroes).

SQL server returns a standard notation `x.yEz` or `2.059E+10`.

You need to change the data type of the `id` column to be a text type (VARCHAR...)

Comment: The data type is Varchar in the table, but yeah the value is being treated as a number.